# Outlook - synchronize external calendar to a default calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

MS Outlook can display in [Todo bar only a default calendar](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/15803533-add-additional-calendars-to-the-to-do-bar). I need to view my private google calendar there. I use a workaround at this moment, that I add my exchange email address to calendar items in Google calendar. But this is an extra step and it happens that I forgot to do this step.

The good solution would be some synchronization tool or VB script that copies all items from one calendar to the default calendar. I have already imported google calendar using a share link so I can view its events in a calendar view. Is there a way to copy the items my default calendar?